Unable to install libffi-dev on Debian 8: 404 errors and "_ctypes" module issue
We have a Debian 8 (Jessie) cluster. I am trying to install a software which resulted error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' 

As a remedy, I attempted: sudo apt-get install libffi-dev as per support platform
This led to error:
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/libf/libffi/libffi-dev_3.1-2+deb8u1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]

I followed these suggestions. Now, my /etc/apt/sources.list file looks like:
deb     http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb     http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main

deb     http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main

# apt-get -t jessie-backports install "package"
deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://www.chem.ucl.ac.uk/repo/ jessie main

Still, the issue is not solved and I am getting error:
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/libf/libffi/libffi-dev_3.1-2+deb8u1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.66.132 80]

Your advice is highly appreciated. Please help me in rectifying the error.

Did you run sudo apt update after editing your configuration?

@Stephen Kitt Thanks so much. Following your instructions I could set up libffi-dev:amd64 (3.1-2+deb8u1) on my Linux HPC.
However, the issue "No module named '_ctypes' " still persists. Please see below :
File "/opt/spack-votca/spack/lib/spack/external/archspec/vendor/cpuid/cpuid.py", line 10, in 
import ctypes
File "/opt/python-3.11.5/lib/python3.11/ctypes/init.py", line 8, in 
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
Sugegstions?

You should ask whoever installed /opt/python-3.11.5...

I myself installed python-3.11.5. It is working fine at other fonts. Do you suggest any troubleshooting approach? Thanks

OK, you need to re-install it after the libffi-dev installation (see the SO post you linked to).

@Stephen Kitt: Thanks a bunch. Reinstallation solved the _ctypes module not found problem.

When apt reports 404 errors, that usually means that its local copies of the repositories are out of date. You can fix that by running sudo apt update; you should then be able to install libffi-dev.
Once that’s done, you’ll need to re-install Python; libffi-dev is used during the Python build.

Thanks @Stephen Kitt. I followed your sugegstions and it worked.

I know, I wrote it up as an answer because comments aren’t permanent.
